# Dynamically display different object attributes

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the values of attributes of different object types dynamically.

I have multiple tabs, in which I display lists containing objects of the same type in each tab.
Because the objects differ in types, I have an object containing arrays which contain the names of the attributes of each object type.

Example:

```
objectTypesAttributes = {
Type_A: ['1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4'],
Type_B: ['a.b',
  'c.d',
  'e.f',
  'g']};
```

In my HTML code I have two ngFor loops. The outer to display all objects of one type in the list. The secound one to display all attributes of a object.

```
<tr *ngFor="let t of tmp">
  <!-- do something... -->

   <!-- trying to access the value of the attribute of the object from the outer ngFor -->
   <td *ngFor="let attribute of objectTypesAttributes[objectType]" [innerText]="t.attribute "></td>

  </td>
</tr>
```

In the inner loop, as you can see, I want to use the the attribute name strings to access get the value from the outer loop object.
Somehow this is not working for the inner loop. It displays 'undefined' or nothing at all.

I tried so far things like

```
[innerText]="t.attribute "
```

OR

```
<td *ngFor="let attribute of objectTypesAttributes[objectType]">{{t[attribute]}}</td>
```

and a lot of other combinations, without a working solution.

Comment: Can you tell, what could be the possible value for `tmp2[objectType]` in inner loop. Because I don't see anything iterable in your object properties data.

Comment: The possible values are all the attributes of the objectTypesAttributes object, where objectType can be either A or B. I edited the example so that it is more understandable.

Comment: What does `tmp` refer now? Is it `objectTypesAttributes` or some other array?

Comment: As I described, the outer loop is an array of all objects of a type. This is in my example 'tmp'. 'tmp' has specific attributes, but as I want to use one code fragment for each type, I have saved the attribute names for each type in another array, 'objectTypesAttributes' in my example code.